# Objective C parse text file into CGPoint object

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, core-animation

In my app, I am trying to load in rows of tab delimited x y t values from `foo.txt` and animate the path on the screen using `CABasicAnimation` and I'm trying to get the animation to speed up/slow down depending on the t values in each row of `foo.txt`.

**So I guess this question has two parts: how do I load in the file and parse the values easily of `foo.txt` on iOS without making hundreds of fscanf calls, and how do I make the animation change speed programmatically?**

Here are 4 sample rows of `foo.txt`, time is in milliseconds:

```
x      y      t
200    300    698
250    322    827
484    192    858
286    752    907
```

I'm almost certain there must be a really efficient way of doing the following but my first thought was to create a `Point` object:

```
@interface Point : NSObject {
CGFloat x;
CGFloat y;
CGFloat t; }
```

And, assuming the values in `foo.txt` get transferring into `SOMETHING`, I can cast each value as a CGFloat and transfer it into `pathMutable`, which I can iterate over for my pathing later.

```
// somehow load and parse foo.txt intelligently, place values in the SOMETHING object
// not sure how in objective-c besides reinventing the wheel with fscanf    

for (int i = 0; i<[SOMETHING count]; i++) {   
        Point * p = [SOMETHING objectAtIndex:i];  //pseudocode
        NSArray * tempVal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(p.x,p.y)], nil];
        [pathMutable addObject:tempVal];  

    }
```

My current xy-only pathing is:

```
UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
for (int i = 0; i<[pathMutable count]; i++) {
    NSValue * val = [pathMutable objectAtIndex:i];
    CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue];

    if (i == 0) {
        [path moveToPoint:p];
    }
    else {
        [path addLineToPoint:p];
    }
}
```

Looking into the documentation for animation pathing, I noticed a lot of the methods only need x and y, and when you start your animation you define total `duration` of the animation, and `fromValue` and `toValue`. How do I hook my individual time values into this?

Comment: If you have two questions, please post them as separate questions.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I'm new to the site, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking two questions, I will only answer one.  It isn't hard to parse a well structured file like that, and there are plenty of SO questions about parsing already.  As for the second part, the class you want is [CAKeyframeAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).  This will give you fine control over the animation behavior.